# Google Cloud Platform // Python script for unZipping files in Bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Hi and thank you for reading.
I'm new GCP, and I still can't find a solution to my problem.
I've searched many topics but no solution helped me move on.

***INPUT INFORMATION***

I have files stored in my bucket in Cloud Storage.

These files could be of any extension, but I need to select only `.zip`s

I want to write a python script in App-Engine, which will find and select these zip files then unzip them in the same directory in Cloud Storage

***Below version of the script, which doesn't work***

```
from google.cloud import storage
from zipfile import ZipFile
 


def list_blobs(bucket_name):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)
    
    for blob in blobs:
        try:
            with ZipFile(f'{blob.name}', 'r') as zipObj:
                zipObj.extractall()
        except:
            print(f'{blob.name} not supported unzipping')

list_blobs('test_bucket_for_me_05_08_2021')
```

Output

```
proxy.txt not supported unzipping
test.zip not supported unzipping
```

Comment: To point you in the right direction, you can't get the data via `blob.name`.  You need to use some other part of `storage_client ` to get the contents of the file.

Answer (score 2):

I find solution, this code below will unzipped zips in bucket

```
from google.cloud import storage
from zipfile import ZipFile
from zipfile import is_zipfile
import io

storage_client = storage.Client()


def unzip_files(bucketname):
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucketname)
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucketname)
  

    for blob in blobs:
        file = bucket.blob(blob.name)
        try:
            zipbytes = io.BytesIO(file.download_as_string())
            if is_zipfile(zipbytes):
                with ZipFile(zipbytes, 'r') as selected_zip:
                    for files_in_zip in selected_zip.namelist():
                        file_in_zip = selected_zip.read(files_in_zip)
                        blob_new = bucket.blob(files_in_zip)
                        blob_new.upload_from_string(file_in_zip)
        except:
            print(f'{blob.name} not supported')

unzip_files("test_bucket_for_me_05_08_2021")
```

Of course , i will modify this code, but this solution works

Thanks all for your time and effort